# Is there a way to implement some sort of auto translation in an react native app?

Tags: react-native, translate

I know this isn't google, but I wasn't able to find anything usefull and maybe you can give me some advice.

What I am looking for is some way to add an auto translation to strings in my react native application.

Right now I am using a workaround in which I translate some of the most common words manually - since that doesn't cover the whole language the outcome looks pretty unsatisfying :)

Comment: Any translation packages is there to support in react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [react-native-i18n](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n).

```
var I18n = require('react-native-i18n');

var Demo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Text>{I18n.t('greeting')}</Text>
    )
  }
});

// Enable fallbacks if you want `en-US` and `en-GB` to fallback to `en`
I18n.fallbacks = true;

I18n.translations = {
  en: {
    greeting: 'Hi!'
  },
  fr: {
    greeting: 'Bonjour!'
  }
}
```

Comment: I looked into this one and I still would end up filling in the translations manually and also the content which I need to transalte isnt static. It's some feed I get through an API

Comment: My guess is that you should not do this, as it can lead to missunderstandings.
If you still want to do this you could have a look at the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/). But I have no experience with that,

Comment: @noa-dev please don't ship an app with google-translated text. I promise you it won't end well!

Comment: @BenClayton I appreciate your honesty. The part of the App that I want to be translated with google, or some other tool is targeted towards Truck drivers. They open the App, navigate to the correct Screen and see a List of Live traffic information. There are keywords like traffic jam, accident, closed lane, closed exit etc. that need to be translated so that the truck driver can understand it - so I need some way to translate it to them:)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to provide a translation via `i18n` for those keywords?

Comment: @schinknbrot I am already translating some of them "manually" with custom scripts but since I can't think of all possible keywords it's the last solution I would consider :)

Comment: @noa-dev and I guess that for simple keywords, Google Translate would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

take user phone OS language using device info

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getdevicelocale`

or using

`I18n = require('react-native-i18n')
locale = I18n.currentLocale()`

then Use power translator

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-power-translator`

//set your device language as a Target_Language on app start

`TranslatorConfiguration.setConfig('Provider_Type', 'Your_API_Key','Target_Language', 'Source_Language');`

//Fill with your own details

`TranslatorConfiguration.setConfig(ProviderTypes.Google, 'xxxx','fr');`

Use it as a component

`<PowerTranslator text={'Engineering physics or engineering science refers to the study of the combined disciplines of physics'} />`

add-on : 
Use redux store or async storage to store all your string on first app start.
Then use translated text from store or storage.
IT will save your api bill as you have fixed strings.

Answer (score 0):

sir for auto-translate. you can create one component where you can pass all strings (text) in your app, And use '@aws-sdk/client-translate' for translation, it's very fast and also works on dynamic data  \

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-translate/index.html

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-translate

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free translating npm package

An example is `free-translate`.

Example usage would be

```
const { translate } = require('free-translate');

(async () => {
  const translatedText = await translate('Hello World', { from: 'en', to: 'ja' });

  console.log(translatedText); // こんにちは世界
})();
```

or you could use something like `react-native-translator` to achieve a similar effect